# Property filter is not available for type Observable<any> despite importing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I want to filter a list of names which I get from an API. I want to do so with the filter operator. But I get this error:

```
> Property filter is not available for type Observable<any>
```

despite importing

```
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

I took this tutorial of Josh Morony as an orientation: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

My Code:

service.ts

```
  getList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
      }
```

page.ts

```
 public searchTerm: string = "";
 userList: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {

    this.getAllUsers();
}


  getAllUsers() {
    this.userList = this.userService.getList()
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
  }


filterUsers (searchTerm) {
  return this.userList.filter (user => {
    return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
}

SearchList() {
  this.userList = this.filterUsers (this.searchTerm);
}
```

page.html

```
<ion-searchbar mode="ios" class="items-searchbar" animated mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionChange)="searchList()" placeholder="Filter by name..."></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between RxJS's [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator, and JavaScript's [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The RxJS `filter` operator excludes observable from the stream that meets a certain condition, whereas the `Array.filter()`  filters/removes objects or values from the array based on a certain condition

For the purpose of your question, you will need to subscribe to the `userList` observable, before filtering the returned observables. This is when you can return the filtered results, which will be used for the `SearchList` method.

```
filterUsers(searchTerm) {
  this.userList.subscribe(res => {
    const result = res.filter(user => {
      return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
    return result; 
  }); 
}

SearchList() {
  this.userList = this.filterUsers(this.searchTerm);
}
```

Comment: and get rid of the SearchList function ? What do I have then for the ionChange?

Comment: @ColinRagnarök the `SearchList` method can remain as it is. The only thign you need to change is the `filterUsers`.

Comment: I have updated my code. Hope it explains it clearer

Comment: The problem I face that I get for `this.userList` in the SearchList function the error that type void function can't be applied type observable<any>

Answer (score 1):

You have to use filter inside pipe(), after map()

Comment: I did that for purpose since I orientated by that tutorial by Josh Moroni who declares pipes to be low in performance. https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Comment: That is about the HTML formatting 'Angular pipes'. In this context however the pipe is for operations on RxJS observables, you will _need_ to use 'RxJS pipes' with the `.pipe(map(...), filter(...))`. These are entirely different things, and rxjs' pipe is by no means not performant.